# Author unregistered

Tags: support, new-users

I posted a answer here: [Angles in three dimensional space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62679/angles-in-three-dimensional-space)

But in that post, the author is "unregistered".
How can I specify that response as being posted by me?

Answer (score 10):

Use https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact to contact the StackExchange staff: they can merge your accounts together.

Comment: Thank you so much. My two accounts were properly joined.